# YOLO: Merging modules trained with the same classes

Tags: merge, yolov5

I'm trying to merge two weights model in a new one. The problem is that my two trained model, A and B, have a different number of layers respect the base yolov5s model(I've trained those models starting with yolov5s.pt weights).

I haven't done some changes on the base model when i created modelA and modelB.
The two, in fact, are the same model created in two different directory but with the same version of yolov5s as basic weights.
I haven't modified or alterated the file when i downloaded Yolo and i've only used the weights to train my model.
The only change that i can think of is the number of classes but i thougth that was not correlated with the layers of the model.

I've replicated the setting in a new environment and this are all the steps and passage that i have done:

- First, i explain the dataset. I'm working on window and belt detector in selfies or photo taken inside the car to distinguish if a person is the driver or a passenger.
- There are 4 different classes: (PassengerBelt, DriverBelt, PassengerWindow and DriverWindow)
- For this test i have 2 little dataset of two different person (A and B):

  - A --> 104 train images and 44 for validation
  - B --> 76 train images and 30 for validation
    All images have only Driver or Passenger classes, and the distribution of the objects is nearly equal.

Here the steps to replicate the environment:

1. Downloaded, from the latest version "v7", the model "yolov5s.pt" and the source code for the requirments
2. Create in a new directory a virtual environment with pipenv
3. Installed in the virtual environment the requirements necessary for the correct function of the model, with the command `pipenv install --requirements ./yolov5-7.0`
4. I've installed the correct version of pytorch for working with cuda, with the command `pipenv install torch torchvision torchaudio --index https://download.pytorch.org/whl/cu117`
5. Training of ModelA `python .\yolov5-7.0\train.py --epochs 150 --batch-size -1 --img 384 --data modelA.yaml --name modelA --weights yolov5s.pt --project train`
6. Training of ModelB `python .\yolov5-7.0\train.py --epochs 150 --batch-size -1 --img 384 --data modelB.yaml --name modelB --weights yolov5s.pt --project train`
7. At the start of the training i've received this warning

```
C:\Users\Davide\.virtualenvs\EnvTest-85QvB3Ib\lib\site-packages\seaborn\_oldcore.py:1498: FutureWarning: is_categorical_dtype is deprecated and will be removed in a future version. Use isinstance(dtype, CategoricalDtype) instead
  if pd.api.types.is_categorical_dtype(vector):
C:\Users\Davide\.virtualenvs\EnvTest-85QvB3Ib\lib\site-packages\seaborn\_oldcore.py:1119: FutureWarning: use_inf_as_na option is deprecated and will be removed in a future version. Convert inf values to NaN before operating instead.
  with pd.option_context('mode.use_inf_as_na', True):
```

And this Traceback at the end

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Davide\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\threading.py", line 1009, in _bootstrap_inner
Exception in thread Thread-18 (plot_images):
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Davide\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\threading.py", line 1009, in _bootstrap_inner
    self.run()
  File "C:\Users\Davide\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\threading.py", line 946, in run
    self.run()
  File "C:\Users\Davide\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\threading.py", line 946, in run
    self._target(*self._args, **self._kwargs)
    self._target(*self._args, **self._kwargs)
  File "E:\TirocinioVero\text_and_drive\Terza_Fase\EnvTest\yolov5-7.0\utils\plots.py", line 305, in plot_images
  File "E:\TirocinioVero\text_and_drive\Terza_Fase\EnvTest\yolov5-7.0\utils\plots.py", line 305, in plot_images
    annotator.box_label(box, label, color=color)
  File "E:\TirocinioVero\text_and_drive\Terza_Fase\EnvTest\yolov5-7.0\utils\plots.py", line 91, in box_label
    annotator.box_label(box, label, color=color)
  File "E:\TirocinioVero\text_and_drive\Terza_Fase\EnvTest\yolov5-7.0\utils\plots.py", line 91, in box_label
    w, h = self.font.getsize(label)  # text width, height
AttributeError: 'FreeTypeFont' object has no attribute 'getsize'
    w, h = self.font.getsize(label)  # text width, height
AttributeError: 'FreeTypeFont' object has no attribute 'getsize'
```

But it seems the training ad gone well.

8. I've started the merging program
   `merge.py`

```
import torch
from torch import nn

# Load the model state dictionaries
modelA = torch.hub.load('ultralytics/yolov5', 'custom', path='./models/modelA.pt')
sdA = modelA.state_dict()

modelB = torch.hub.load('ultralytics/yolov5', 'custom', path='./models/modelA.pt')
sdB = modelB.state_dict()

# Merge the state dictionaries
sdC = {}
for key in sdA: 
    sdC[key] = (sdA[key] + sdB[key]) / 2

# Create a new model with the merged weights
modelC = torch.hub.load('ultralytics/yolov5', 'custom', "./yolov5s.pt")
modelC.load_state_dict(sdC)

# Save the merged model
torch.save(modelC.state_dict(), "./models/merge.pt")

# Load the merged model
merged_model = torch.hub.load('ultralytics/yolov5', 'custom', path='./models/merge.pt')
```

Traceback

```
Using cache found in C:\Users\Davide/.cache\torch\hub\ultralytics_yolov5_master
WARNING  invalid check_version(5.9.5, ) requested, please check values.
YOLOv5  2023-8-16 Python-3.10.0 torch-2.0.1+cu117 CUDA:0 (NVIDIA GeForce GTX 1050 Ti, 4096MiB)

Fusing layers...
Model summary: 157 layers, 7020913 parameters, 0 gradients, 15.8 GFLOPs
Adding AutoShape...
Using cache found in C:\Users\Davide/.cache\torch\hub\ultralytics_yolov5_master
WARNING  invalid check_version(5.9.5, ) requested, please check values.
YOLOv5  2023-8-16 Python-3.10.0 torch-2.0.1+cu117 CUDA:0 (NVIDIA GeForce GTX 1050 Ti, 4096MiB)

Fusing layers...
Model summary: 157 layers, 7020913 parameters, 0 gradients, 15.8 GFLOPs
Adding AutoShape...
Using cache found in C:\Users\Davide/.cache\torch\hub\ultralytics_yolov5_master
WARNING  invalid check_version(5.9.5, ) requested, please check values.
YOLOv5  2023-8-16 Python-3.10.0 torch-2.0.1+cu117 CUDA:0 (NVIDIA GeForce GTX 1050 Ti, 4096MiB)

Fusing layers...
YOLOv5s summary: 213 layers, 7225885 parameters, 0 gradients
Adding AutoShape...
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "E:\TirocinioVero\text_and_drive\Terza_Fase\EnvTest\merge.py", line 18, in <module>
    modelC.load_state_dict(sdC)
  File "C:\Users\Davide\.virtualenvs\EnvTest-85QvB3Ib\lib\site-packages\torch\nn\modules\module.py", line 2041, in load_state_dict
    raise RuntimeError('Error(s) in loading state_dict for {}:\n\t{}'.format(
RuntimeError: Error(s) in loading state_dict for AutoShape:
        size mismatch for model.model.model.24.m.0.weight: copying a param with shape torch.Size([27, 128, 1, 1]) from checkpoint, the shape in current model is torch.Size([255, 128, 1, 1]).
        size mismatch for model.model.model.24.m.0.bias: copying a param with shape torch.Size([27]) from checkpoint, the shape in current model is torch.Size([255]).
        size mismatch for model.model.model.24.m.1.weight: copying a param with shape torch.Size([27, 256, 1, 1]) from checkpoint, the shape in current model is torch.Size([255, 256, 1, 1]).
        size mismatch for model.model.model.24.m.1.bias: copying a param with shape torch.Size([27]) from checkpoint, the shape in current model is torch.Size([255]).
        size mismatch for model.model.model.24.m.2.weight: copying a param with shape torch.Size([27, 512, 1, 1]) from checkpoint, the shape in current model is torch.Size([255, 512, 1, 1]).
        size mismatch for model.model.model.24.m.2.bias: copying a param with shape torch.Size([27]) from checkpoint, the shape in current model is torch.Size([255]).
```

The error show me that i have models with different sizes, but i don't know why the layer of my trained models have changed in number.

Answer (score 0):

```py
#coding: utf-8
from PIL import Image, ImageDraw, ImageFont

image = Image.open("test_combine_word.png")
text = "hello world"
draw = ImageDraw. Draw(image)
font1 = ImageFont.truetype("Arial.ttf", 20)
font_size = font1.getbbox(text)
print (font_size)
```

The most recent version of the Pillow library has removed the 'getsize' method. Try to use 'getbbox' instead.

Comment: Please do not post code or errors as image. [edit] your answer and use formatted text instead.